# How to implement Runnable for the given code?

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

I'm trying to play sounds on tap of a button.
Initially the sound is played on tap, but after repeated tap of a button the sound isn't played anymore. 
All the required files are placed in respective folders.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/one"
        android:onClick="tapped"
        android:tag="0"
        android:text="@string/one"
        tools:text="@string/one" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/two"
        android:onClick="tapped"
        android:tag="1"
        android:text="@string/two"
        tools:text="@string/two" />

        </GridLayout>
```

Here's what I have done as of now,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 int myMusic[] = {R.raw.one,R.raw.two};

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }


 public void tapped ( final View view){
        Button buttonVar = (Button) view;
        int tagNo;
        tagNo = Integer.parseInt(buttonVar.getTag().toString());
        MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[tagNo]);
        sound.start();
```

Comment: What has this to do with implementing `Runnable`?

Comment: The online course instructor says that the code for sound has to be run on a separate thread. And after searching here I learnt that 'Runnable and Handler' concepts are used for it. Tried my best to use them but couldn't get the result.

Answer (score 2):

release your mediaplayer after you are done with it.
you are creating multiple mediaplayer instances and that is causing the problem.

use-

```
    sound.release();
```

Comment: If I use 'sound.release();' after the 'sound.start();' the sound isn't played at all and I get the message **mediaplayer went away with unhandled events** in Logcat

Comment: release your mediaplayer when you are done with it !!! for eg-on next button click. And you don't need to use handler to get it done. A new thread will get the job done.

Comment: With just one onClick function taking input from all the buttons, if I use `sound.release();` inside this onClick, it's crashing the app. Even if I use individual onClicks for each button and use `.release();` in each of them, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from sourabh's answer (to release the used MediaPlayer), to properly implement multi-threading (as the question asks) you will need to submit a runnable into a ThreadPool.

Google/Android provides documentation on ExecutorService(s), linked below, which you can follow to get an understanding on how to run chunks of code on new threads.

Beware though, as when running things async you can still have duplicate playback (unless not handled) as multiple audio sources will be started (one for each submitted thread).

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html